# why cv::stereoRectify return ROI with size(0,0)

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d, calibration

I'm learning opencv and testing a stereocamera. In my code, the stereoRectify function sometimes return ROI with its size(0,0).
I cannot figure this problem out.

```
Mat cameraMatrix[2], distCoeffs[2];
cameraMatrix[0] = initCameraMatrix2D(objectPoints, imagePoints_l, 
  imageSize, 0);
cameraMatrix[1] = initCameraMatrix2D(objectPoints, imagePoints_r, 
  imageSize, 0);

Mat R, T, E, F;
double rms = stereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints_l, imagePoints_r,
  cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0],
  cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1],
  imageSize, R, T, E, F,
  CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO +
  CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST +
  CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS +
  CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH +
  CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL +
  CALIB_FIX_K3 + CALIB_FIX_K4 + CALIB_FIX_K5,
  TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, 100, 1e-5));

Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
Rect validRoi[2];

stereoRectify(cameraMatrix[0], distCoeffs[0],
  cameraMatrix[1], distCoeffs[1],
  imageSize, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q,
  CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 0.5, imageSize, &validRoi[0], &validRoi[1]);

cout << validRoi[0] << validRoi[1] << endl;
```

It output in terminal:

```
[0 x 0 from (0, 0)][215 x 184 from (77, 19)]
```

or:

```
[0 x 0 from (0, 0)][0 x 0 from (0, 0)]
```

I also output the camera matrix and distortion matrix:

```
[204.3355426705726, 0, 193.3280616575545;
0, 189.8976931576431, 123.307676870377;
0, 0, 1]
[-0.5404320611827982, 0.3292134879059271, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.1371856537119246, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[204.3355426705726, 0, 183.756931129648;
0, 189.8976931576431, 131.4500619272754;
0, 0, 1]
[-0.524923482702874, 0.3121043629068334, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.1269780773557047, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

As for now (31.03.2018, opencv 3.4.1), many users report stereo rectify to return invalid results:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11131

Answer (score 0):

The stereoRectify function returns maybe no valid ROI. Please post the full Code.

Did you do a Stereo-Calibration before? 
What are you`re input matrices? Are the camera matrices the output matrices from the Stereo-Calibration?
Did you try to set the free scale parameter aplha = 0? Then the ROI covers the whole images.
Can you please post the rectified images?

Here is a full StereoCalibration example for OpenCV:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stereo_calib.cpp

and the OpenCV-Documentation for StereoRectify:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify

Answer (score 0):

At first check you`re stereoCalibration flags. Look at the OpenCV-Documentation which flag do you really need. You can try it first without any flag.

Did you check the returned rms-value from the stereo-Calibration? A good calibration returns a rms less than 1.

Are you`re images well rectified? You can remap and show it with the following code:

```
// remap
Mat rmap[2][2];
initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, P1, imageSize, CV_16SC2, rmap[0][0], rmap[0][1]);
initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R2, P2, imageSize, CV_16SC2, rmap[1][0], rmap[1][1]);
Mat out1, out2;
remap(img1, out1, rmap[0][0], rmap[0][1], CV_INTER_LINEAR);
remap(img2, out2, rmap[1][0], rmap[1][1], CV_INTER_LINEAR);
Mat result;
hconcat(out1, out2, result);

// draw horizontal line
for(int j = 0; j < result.rows; j += 16 ) {
    line(result, Point(0, j), Point(result.cols, j), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8);
}

// show
imshow("result", result);
waitKey();
```